# Angular Http request extremely slow

Tags: angular, laravel, api, rest, http-headers

My angular 2 application connects to a laravel api service. When i make the call via Postman, it takes about 500ms. But when the call is executed via the Angular application it takes about 8+ seconds to load.

It looks like the request is in a pending state for a very long time. When you click the button to navigate to the slow page, the requests are shown in the network tab and the app freezes, the requests in the network tab show a pending state.

After a while when the page is fully loaded the request in the network tab of Edge says 800ms. It looks like the request itself is okay but for some reason it takes a long time before it executes. I've added a performance counter in the interceptor. The interceptor performance informs  16299.5 milliseconds.

After research I've implemented the Connection: close to the headers but on my site it errors: Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

I've also added the ngOnDestroy but this also does not seem to affect the speed.

Edit: There is a sygnificant difference between chrom / firefox and Edge. Seems like Edge is many times more slow than the other 2.

Any ideas why it is this slow?

**Code**

api.service.ts

```
getRequest(url: string, requestParams: any = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + url, {params: requestParams});
}
```

authentication.interceptor.ts

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const begin = performance.now();
    const authData = this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationData();

    if (authData){
      const head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authData.plainTextToken};
      const modifiedRequest = request.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders(head).set('X-UserId', authData.curUser['UserId'].toString())
      });
      return next.handle(modifiedRequest).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.logRequestTime(begin, request.url, request.method);
        })
      );
    }else{
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.logRequestTime(begin, request.url, request.method);
        })
      );
    }
}

private logRequestTime(startTime: number, url: string, method: string): void {
    const requestDuration = `${performance.now() - startTime}`;
}
```

overview.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiSource = this.store.fetchApi().subscribe(responseData => {
        this.store.addArrayData(responseData);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.apiSource.unsubscribe();
}
```

Postman:

[image: postman repsponse time]

Network pending:
[image: network tab]

***Edit 13:11***
ive found that during the request the cpu goes to 100%.
[image: cpu performance]

Comment: Please post a sandbox of your app that reproduces the error

Comment: Dear @CodeWhisperer there is no error. for the request itself. Only the Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" when i add the Connection header.

This is less relevant to the question. It is all about why the http request is this slow.

Comment: What does the backend server says in both cases ?

Comment: in the server logs there are just these lines:
204 OPTIONS /api/v1/project HTTP/1.0
204 OPTIONS /api/v1/type HTTP/1.0
200 GET /api/v1/project HTTP/1.0
200 GET /api/v1/type HTTP/1.0

Comment: what is your `this.authenticationService.user`? (it's a strange name for an observable). Your `this.authenticationService.user` call to an httpClient?, see that in this case pass througth the interceptor creating a "loop". Are you sure about the use of `exhaustMap` and not `switchMap` rxjs operator?

Comment: I've edited the interceptor to the following (see the question details). this has no effect, the request is still slow.